# Python Bottle convert output to html

Tags: python, sqlite, bottle

I have been playing with Bottle and Python.
My problem is:

I have some rows in database and I can get them as a output in view files.

But There are some html tags on the rows which shows as tags instead of converting them. Such as,

```
<b>TEST</b>
```

shows :

```
<b>TEST</b>
```

Instead of:

> **TEST**

What can i do about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,

> {{!row}}

Did the trick. I returned row in the template.